# send file (content) with deleteFile request for fine-uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using fine-uploader to upload multiple files via Ajax. I need file content on deleteFile request and not just file qquuid. I see that I can add params to delete request, but I can't figure out how to attach file with the POST request for the recently uploaded file for which delete is clicked.

Can I have access to file id for which delete is clicked and then use this id to attach file in params by using [getFile(id)](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getFile) method like following:

```
deleteFile: {
    enabled: true,
    endpoint: <deleteFileEndPoint>,
    method: 'POST',
    forceConfirm: true,
    params: {file: getFile(file_id)}
}
```

I don't know how to access fileUploader API methods in this case.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry this is not supported.  I doubt support will be added either as it seems a bit odd to re-upload the file you want to delete as part of the delete file request.  In order for that to work cross browser, the request would have to be multipart encoded as well.